# Accelerometer dataset for car crash detection

Tags: data-request, cars, sensors, accelerometer

I'm trying to find an open-source dataset for car crash detection using sensor data including accelerometer. Is there any open-source dataset available? Basically I want to detect car crashes only using non-car information, such as accelerometer data from a smartphone mounted on a car.

I was told about [FARS](https://www.nhtsa.gov/research-data/fatality-analysis-reporting-system-fars), but wasn't really sure if this is what I want. I couldn't find a accelerometer dataset there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the NHTSA FAR data, you may want to look at the [NHTSA Vehicle Crash Test Database](https://www-nrd.nhtsa.dot.gov/database/veh/veh.htm). This does contain accelerometer data.

That said, I doubt they are using a phone's accelerometer to create this dataset.